# Interpretation of proposition in textbook

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading Algebra by Michael Artin and I have a question about a section of text.

Proposition 1.2.13: Let $M'=[A'\mid|B']$ be a block row echelon matrix, where $B'$ is a column vector. The system of equations $A'X=B'$ has a solution iff there is no pivot in the last column, $B'$. **In that case, arbitrary values can be assigned to the unknown $x_i$, provided that (column $i$) does not contain a pivot.** When these arbitrary values are assigned, the other unknowns are determined uniquely.

Why is the bold text true?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a pivot? I have never come across this word in this context before.

Comment: @FlybyNight I assume he means the columns that contain leading 1's in non-zero rows in the row echelon form.

Comment: @FlybyNight A pivot is a leading nonzero entry in a row of a row-echelon matrix.

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos The book refers to a "*pivot in the last column*".

Comment: @FlybyNight a pivot in the last column of the block matrix they've described would mean that the system is degenerate. e.g. 0x_1 + 0x_2 + ... 0x_n = A with A!=0. So the row that has a pivot in the last column would be zeros followed by a single nonzero entry.

Comment: @AbhishekMallela I'm pretty sure that the bold text is just talking about the existence of free variables in the system. Its a criteria for free variables that if you have a row-echelon matrix and a column without a pivot then the variable represented by that column is a free variable.

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos +1

Comment: I don't mean to be snarky, but does the proposition also have a proof in the textbook?

Comment: The point here is that a pivot in the *last* column would mean you had an equation of the form $0 = \text{nonzero}$. There is a standard algorithm for getting the general solution where you solve for the *pivot* variables in terms of the *free* or nonpivot variables. See Artin's example (1.2.11) on p. 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k$ be the columns in $A'$ with pivots and $w_1,w_2,\dots w_{m}$ those columns of $A'$ that don't contain a pivot.

Then your linear system can be written as
$$
y_1v_1+y_2v_2+\dots+y_kv_k=B'-z_1w_1-z_2w_2-\dots-z_mw_m
$$
where I have renamed the unknowns $x_1,x_2,\dots$ so not to use double subscripts.

This system, considered only in the unknowns $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_k$ has a (unique) solution for every value you assign to $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_m$, because it has triangular form and all columns (except for the last, of course) have a pivot in them: indeed, multiplying a column for a scalar can't introduce new pivots.

Comment: Thank you all for your input